# TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

I'm trying to create a javascript discord bot that will give the user a role when clicking on an emoji of a specific comment (react role), but i'm getting this following code error

code:

```
client.on('raw', async data => {
    if(data.t !== "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD" && data.t !== "MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE") return
    if(data.d.message_id != "612715176122384414") return

    let canal = client.guilds.get("612380691522387985")
    let cara = canal.members.get(data.d.user_id)

    let novato = canal.roles.get('612715206400802837')

    if(data.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD"){
        if(data.d.emoji.name === "✅"){ 
            if(cara.roles.has(novato)) return 
            cara.addRole(novato) 
        }
    }

    if(data.t === "MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE"){
        if(data.d.emoji.name === "✅"){
            if(cara.roles.has(novato)) return
            cara.removeRole(novato)
        }
    }

})
```

error:

```
(node:1324) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
    at Client.client.on (C:\Users\Ori\Documents\Discord\TesterBot\bot.js:133:22)
    at Client.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Ori\Documents\Discord\TesterBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:317:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Ori\Documents\Discord\TesterBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Ori\Documents\Discord\TesterBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Ori\Documents\Discord\TesterBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\Ori\Documents\Discord\TesterBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:422:14)
    at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\Ori\Documents\Discord\TesterBot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:352:17)
(node:1324) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
```

This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function 
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1324) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero 
exit code.

Comment: Looks like this code `let canal = client.guilds.get("612380691522387985")` returns undefined. Is the id correct?

Comment: Wow, I was putting the channel id and not the server id lol, thanks for the help Clarity !!!